# Path from URL not from C:/ Drive

Tags: vb.net

I found one code which auto-change proxies from own text file located in computer.
Now I would like to rather this get path from my own URL where I store my private list of proxies, so what I have to change in the code please? and could also someone explain why? thank you.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Form1

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\name\Documents\proxylist.txt"
    Dim label As String
    Public proxy(2000) As String
    Public index As Integer = 0
    Public max_proxys As Integer = 0
    Dim a As String
    Dim start_check As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If (start_check > 0) Then
            index = 0
            Do While index <> max_proxys
                proxy(index) = ""
                index = index + 1
            Loop
            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                FILE_NAME = "C:\Users\name\Documents\proxylist.txt"
            End If

        End If
        If TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
            FILE_NAME = TextBox3.Text
        End If
        Try
            Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(FILE_NAME)
            index = 0
            Do While reader.Peek <> -1

                a = reader.ReadLine
                proxy(index) = a.ToString
                index = index + 1

            Loop
            max_proxys = index
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("File Not Found")
            Timer1.Stop()
        End Try

        label = "true"
        index = 0
        TextBox1.Text = proxy(0)
        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            Timer1.Interval = 1000 'ms
        Else
            Try
                Dim a As Integer = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox2.Text)
                Timer1.Interval = a * 1000 'ms
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & "Please Enter Valid Time in Seconds ")
                If Timer1.Enabled Then
                    Timer1.Stop()
                End If
            End Try

        End If
        start_check = 1
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        label = "false"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim clsProxy As New IEProxy
        clsProxy.DisableProxy()

    End Sub




    Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
        TextBox1.Text = proxy(index)
        index = index + 1
        Dim clsProxy As New IEProxy
        If clsProxy.SetProxy(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Proxy successfully enabled.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error enabling proxy.", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
        If index >= max_proxys Then
            index = 0
        End If
        If label.Equals("false") Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class IEProxy
    Public Enum Options
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5
        INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37
        INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75
        INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39
        PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = &H2
        PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = &H1
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Class FILETIME
        Public dwLowDateTime As Integer
        Public dwHighDateTime As Integer
    End Class

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size:=12)> _
    Private Structure INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
        <FieldOffset(0)> Dim dwOption As Integer
        <FieldOffset(4)> Dim dwValue As Integer
        <FieldOffset(4)> Dim pszValue As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(4)> Dim ftValue As IntPtr

        Public Function GetBytes() As Byte()
            Dim b(12) As Byte
            BitConverter.GetBytes(dwOption).CopyTo(b, 0)
            Select Case dwOption
                Case Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS
                    BitConverter.GetBytes(dwValue).CopyTo(b, 4)
                Case Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS
                    BitConverter.GetBytes(pszValue.ToInt32()).CopyTo(b, 4)
                Case Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER
                    BitConverter.GetBytes(pszValue.ToInt32()).CopyTo(b, 4)
            End Select
            Return b
        End Function
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Class INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
        Public dwSize As Integer
        Public pszConnection As String
        Public dwOptionCount As Integer
        Public dwOptionError As Integer
        Public pOptions As IntPtr
    End Class

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Class INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
        Public dwAccessType As Integer
        Public lpszProxy As IntPtr
        Public lpszProxyBypass As IntPtr
    End Class

    Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122
    Private Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38
    Private Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1

    <DllImport("wininet.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, _
             ByVal dwOption As Integer, _
             ByVal lpBuffer As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST, _
             ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetLastError() As Integer
    End Function

    Public Function SetProxy(ByVal proxy_full_addr As String) As Boolean
        Dim bReturn As Boolean
        Dim list As New INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
        Dim dwBufSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(list)
        Dim opts(3) As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
        Dim opt_size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(opts(0))

        list.dwSize = dwBufSize
        list.pszConnection = ControlChars.NullChar
        list.dwOptionCount = 3

        'set flags
        opts(0).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS
        opts(0).dwValue = Options.PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT Or Options.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY

        'set proxyname
        opts(1).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER
        opts(1).pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy_full_addr)

        'set override
        opts(2).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS
        opts(2).pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

        Dim b(3 * opt_size) As Byte
        opts(0).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 0)
        opts(1).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, opt_size)
        opts(2).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 2 * opt_size)

        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(3 * opt_size)
        Marshal.Copy(b, 0, ptr, 3 * opt_size)

        list.pOptions = ptr
        'Set the options on the connection
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, list, dwBufSize)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        'Notify existing Internet Explorer instances that the settings have changed
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, Nothing, 0)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        'Flush the current IE proxy setting
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, Nothing, 0)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(opts(1).pszValue)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(opts(2).pszValue)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr)
        Return bReturn
    End Function

    Public Function DisableProxy() As Boolean
        Dim bReturn As Boolean
        Dim list As New INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
        Dim dwBufSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(list)
        Dim opts(0) As INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
        Dim opt_size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(opts(0))

        list.dwSize = dwBufSize
        list.pszConnection = ControlChars.NullChar
        list.dwOptionCount = 1

        opts(0).dwOption = Options.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS
        opts(0).dwValue = Options.PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT

        Dim b(opt_size) As Byte
        opts(0).GetBytes().CopyTo(b, 0)

        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(opt_size)
        Marshal.Copy(b, 0, ptr, opt_size)

        list.pOptions = ptr
        'Set the options on the connection
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, list, dwBufSize)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        'Notify existing Internet Explorer instances that the settings have changed
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, Nothing, 0)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        'Flush the current IE proxy setting
        bReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, Options.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, Nothing, 0)
        If Not bReturn Then
            Debug.WriteLine(GetLastError)
        End If

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr)
        Return bReturn
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just download your url to the FILE_NAME location in your form's load event. Be warned that if there is a file at FILE_NAME, this sub I provide you will overwrite it.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim YourURL As String = "http://www.yoururl.com/filename.ext"
    Using w As New System.Net.WebClient
        w.DownloadFile(YourURL, FILE_NAME)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I really need to load proxylist.txt from my url location, as I want to give this someone and I dont want to he download all private proxy:port to his computer, thanks for any other advice and solution

Comment: Also I just realize that code has some issue, as when I check on Whatsmyip in browser IT DOESNT CHANGE proxy from list.txt and I have same IP, so it is even not working :(

Comment: also should I change "YouURL" to my url too? or only change the red url? sorry I am really confused

Comment: Also I tried your method but I get this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: All I am saying is that IF your method works the way it is written, then you can still use your method, IF you put a file(downloaded) there before executing your method.

Comment: Check it again, I forgot to put the "YourURL" variable in the w.DownloadFile call. I updated the answer above.

Comment: All you need to change is what is inside the quotes.

Comment: NO Paul, I try to tell you that I have never tried the whatsmyIP on google, now I have realize it is not working :( the code i have put here ..

Comment: Sorry for you! Good luck