# Progressbar Complete when amount of seconds from textbox

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have some numericupdown(numSec) where I enter exemple 60sec and pgBar (progressbar) that I need he wait till 60sec doen and then popup msbbox and say complete.

The problem is that i can move the progressbar but it doesnt wait till numSec.Text number of seconds entered in the numericupdown.
Can someone help? I have so far just a basic, thank you.

```html
For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(numSec.Value)
        pgBar.Value = i / CInt(numSec.Value) * 100
        Next
```

Comment: One option would be to setup a Timer that fires every second and check to see if the current time is past your target time.  Holding the code in a loop like that typically doesn't work very well with GUI type applications.

Comment: thx Idle_Mind but I am new to this so I have really not much idea if i don't see exempmle, so thx for help but i need code :(

Comment: Btw this pgBar I am tring to insert in this code, posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960974/path-from-url-not-from-c-drive IF OYU HAVE 5min to check and maybe you can tell me where to add it and why, because it has a timer1 and it has 1000 setup so every sec as you mention. Thank you